# Deploying React App created by CRA (Create React App) to different ENVIRONMENTS, that have different URL PATHS?

Tags: reactjs, docker, devops, create-react-app

### Problem:

We have a CRA (Create React App) application that we need to **deploy** to many different **environments**. We're using **Kubernetes** to spawn these **environments** so we will have many of them, the number is not fixed.

The problem is that those environments must be under the **same domain name** and must have the **same path structure**. (this is a business requirement and we cannot influence it).

Example of environments:

```
https://www.example.com/company/app-env01/react_application/
https://www.example.com/company/app-env02/react_application/
https://www.example.com/company/app-env03/react_application/
https://www.example.com/company/app-env-foo/react_application/
https://www.example.com/company/app-env-bar/react_application/
https://www.example.com/company/app/react_application/
```

So the fixed structure is: `https://www.example.com/company/app[-____]/react_application/`

The way to make it work **on a single environment** would be to specify **PUBLIC_URL** in `package.json` `build` script:

```json
    ...
    "build": "PUBLIC_URL=/company/app-env01/react_application react-scripts build",
    ...
```

This works fine for **ONE environment only** (`env01` in this case), but we need to deploy a **single build artifact** (static file bundle) to **MANY different environments**, which have different `PUBLIC_URL`s.

Is this possible to achieve without building the application for every environment?

#### How we build the artifact:

Our deployment artifact is a **Docker image**, which is just **Nginx** serving previously built **React static files**.

#### How we perform routing:

**The Browser** is hitting our **Kubernetes Ingress**, which **strips the path away** and forwards the request to a Docker Container (in a K8S Pod) which is running **Nginx**. **Nginx** is serving the CRA static files under the root directory `/`.

Example:

```
Browser
  ↓
https://www.example.com/company/app-env01/react_application/
  ↓
Ingress
  /
  ↓
Nginx
  ↓
Serves the CRA static files
```

This works fine, the problem (to me at least it seems) is in **React Router**. We are setting the `basename` dynamically, and it is being set correctly (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string). The problem (I assume) is in this `PUBLIC_URL`. Deploying the application without specifying it **does not work**. And it needs to be known **at build time**. That's the main issue.

#### IMPORTANT:

- We are using **React Router**, so it must work properly when the application is deployed
- We want to deploy a **single build artifact** (a single Docker Image) across **all environments**

Comment: Usually, it's the CI that will set/use different ENV variables and automatically set the right `PUBLIC_URL` before building.

Comment: Why do you specify `PUBLIC_URL`? It's not required to build and serve from nginx. Seems like your infrastructure is bleeding into your application.

Comment: ...but since you want to deploy a single build on the different envs, have you thought about just using a relative `PUBLIC_URL`?

Comment: @EmileBergeron Yes, we want to deploy a single build to different environments. We **are** using a relative `PUBLIC_URL` but the problem is that it is different for each environment.

@im_baby Without it, the application is looking for static assets starting from the root "/", which is not the desired behavior. If the application is served under `https://www.example.com/company/app-env01/react_application/` we need (for example) the CSS to be requested from `/company/app-env01/react_application/static/css/`. This is possible when `PUBLIC_URL` is set to `/company/app-env01/react_application/`

Comment: What I mean is, use a relative URL that starts _after_ `company/app-env01/react_application`, like a simple `./` and let your infrastructure do the routing.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution

@Emile got me thinking about using relative URLs again, along with configuring Nginx to handle it correctly. Thank you!

Adding this location block to the Nginx configuration solved the problem:

```
  location ~ .(static)/(js|css|media)/(.+)$ {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/$3;
  }
```

Here's the full configuration (simplified for the sake of clarity):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  
  # This rule internally redirects any relative requests for static files so that they start from the root
  # Example, it internally redirects `/RANDOM/SUBPATH/static/js/main.xxx.chunk.js` to `/static/js/main.xxx.chunk.js`
  # Effectively, it strips everything that comes before `/static...`
  location ~ .(static)/(js|css|media)/(.+)$ {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/$3;
  }

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
 
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
 
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

### Further explanation

The reason that using relative URLs originally did not work is:

This would work just fine:

```
/company/app-env01/react_application/static/js/xxxxxxxx.chunk.js
```

but this would not:

```
/company/app-env01/react_application/RANDOM/SUBPATH/static/js/xxxxxxxx.chunk.js
```

I needed a way to "strip off" the `/RANDOM/SUBPATH` part, whatever that part is, and I achieved it adding the **Nginx** `location` block listed above.